# get <img> tag source out of variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how do i extract all the img html tags out of the javascript variable that looks like this:

```
var content = '<img src="http://website.com/image.jpg"><img src="http://website.com/image2.jpg"><img src="http://website.com/image3.jpg">Other content';
```

And then extract each img link , probably using jQuery .each() function.

Image link extracted will be

```
http://website.com/image.jpg
http://website.com/image2.jpg
http://website.com/image3.jpg
```

How can I do this? do i need regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For single-level DOM this will work nicely:

```
var links = $(content).filter('img').map(function() {
    return this.src;
}).toArray();
console.log(links); //["http://website.com/image.jpg", "http://website.com/image2.jpg", "http://website.com/image3.jpg"]
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/B77G2/8/)

If you have multiple levels of DOM (nested images inside other elements) change first line to:

```
var links = $('<div>').append(content).find('img').map(function() {
```

Also, if you're scraping arbitrary data, you should use [`$.parseHTML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/) (jQuery 1.8+) to be safe from XSS.

Here's the complete, sturdy version:

```
var links = $('<div>').append($.parseHTML(content)).find('img').map(function() {
    return this.src;
}).toArray();
```

### *[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/atetuj/1/edit)*

In the above example, I'm appending the content to a dynamically created `div` element so I can perform just a single `find` operation. The result is the same as @Explosion Pills' `.find('img').addBack().filter('img')` variation.

---

Also, obviously, if you already have the images in the page, you can use a common ancestor as the root for `.find()` instead of creating new DOM elements:

```
var links = $('#imagesParent').find('img').map(function() {
```

Comment: what about there's another tag wrapping those images `<p><img src="http://test.com/aa.jpg"></p>`

Comment: There won't be a problem. Try the multi-level DOM version. Will add a fiddle for it.

Comment: it dosent seem to work after i wrap those img tags with p tag.

Comment: Added a live demo with the last version, no problem. `=]`

Comment: i see you used a div to append the content data to it , wouldnt it create many images duplication on all the divs in the html page?

Comment: @Ravensmith450 Nah, if we don't keep any reference to the generated DOM elements (not appended to the main render DOM nor stored in a variable), it gets garbage collected soon after.

Comment: Also, if you already have the images in the page, you can use the images' parent as a starting point for `$('#imagesParent').find('img').map` instead of obtaining its `.html()`. `=]`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a jQuery collection of html elements from a valid html string without even appending them to any document.  This will work like a normal jQuery collection.

```
$(content).filter('img').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

EDIT: If the images will *always* be the children of another element in `content`, use `.find` instead of `.filter`.  Otherwise, you have to use *both* simultaneously, which you can still do:

```
$(content).find('img').addBack().filter('img').each(function () {
```

Comment: this dosent works when i wrap the img inside another tag for example `<p><img src="http://test.com/aa.jpg"></p>`

Answer (score 0):

You're right, using `.each()` to iterate over it works fine.

```
var ary = [];
var content = '<img src="http://website.com/image.jpg"><img src="http://website.com/image2.jpg"><img src="http://website.com/image3.jpg">Other content';
$(content).each(function () {
    ary.push($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Mn4rU/)**

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/azezaf/1/edit)**</kbd> Using `.map()` and `.get()`

```
var srcs = $(content).map(function(){
    return this.src;
}).get();
```

http://api.jquery.com/map/
http://api.jquery.com/get/

---

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/azezaf/2/edit)**</kbd> Using `.each()` and an array to store data

```
var srcArray = [];
$(content).each(function(){
    srcArray.push(this.src);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/each/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push